# Como gerar uma array com a lista dos arquivos enviados por upload?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tipo quero gerar uma array assim.

```
array('nome1', 'nome2', 'nome3',)
```

o que eu tenho é a string $nome, como eu faço para gerar a array acima ?

seria algo como

```
array($nome)
```

??

meu código

```
if (!empty($_FILES['files'])) {

            $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $len);

            $new_name = convert_accented_characters($string);

            for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];

                $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $fileSize);

                $new_name = convert_accented_characters($string);

                echo $new_name.'<br/>';
            }

            //Configure upload.
            $this->upload->initialize(array(
                "file_name" => array($new_name),
                "upload_path"   => './public/uploads/album/'. $past_date .'/'. $pasta .'/',
                "allowed_types" => "mp3",
                "max_size"  => "2194304000"
            ));
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende? Quer dizer que tem uma/várias variáveis com valores de string guardados e quer colocar essas strings/variáveis dentro de um array?

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo da sua variável `$nome`?

Comment: sim, exatamente isso @Sergio

Comment: nome de arquivos de um input @RodrigoRigotti

Comment: @UellingtonPalma coloquei uma resposta. Era isso que procurava?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para gerar uma array a sintaxe é:

```
$minha_array = array($elemento1, $elemento2, ..., $elementoN); // onde $elementoX é uma variável, string ou array
```

No caso de ter strings já guardadas dentro de variáveis pode fazer da maneira que mostrei em cima.

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';
$minha_array = array($foo, $bar, 'nova string');
echo $minha_array[0]; // dá 'foo'
echo $minha_array[1]; // dá 'bar'
echo $minha_array[2]; // dá 'nova string'
```

Para adicionar novos elementos a uma array pode usar `$minha_array[] = $elemento;`, dessa maneira cada novo elemento será adicionado no final da array.

### Edit:

Adaptando ao seu código pode fazer assim:

```
$nomes = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $fileSize);
    $nomes[] = convert_accented_characters($string);
    // echo $new_name.'<br/>';
}

//Configure upload.
$this->upload->initialize(array(
    "file_name" => $nomes,
    // etc...
```

Comment: Perfeito, e se a string $elemento, estiver guardando vários valores de um loop ?

Comment: @UellingtonPalma nesse caso dentro do loop podes ter `$minha_array[] = $elemento;`, dessa maneira cada novo elemento será adicionado no final da array.

Comment: Acho que isso se encaixa, vou editar minha pergunta e você me fala onde encaixo isso.

Comment: $new_name @Sergio

Comment: @UellingtonPalma editei a resposta com o seu código.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você quer gerar um array contendo a lista dos nomes dos arquivos que serão enviados, se for o caso use colchetes vazios, assim ele define o index automáticamente:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['files'])) {

    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $len);

    $new_name = convert_accented_characters($string);

    // Este será seu array
    $upload_file_names = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];

        $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $fileSize);

        $new_name = convert_accented_characters($string);

        // Cada linha desta adiciona o nome da linha atual em $upload_file_names
        $upload_file_names[] = $new_name;

    }

    //Configure upload.
    $this->upload->initialize(array(
        "file_name" => array($new_name),
        "upload_path"   => './public/uploads/album/'. $past_date .'/'. $pasta .'/',
        "allowed_types" => "mp3",
        "max_size"  => "2194304000"
    ));

}
```

Daí no caso de ter um html assim:

```
<form>
   <input type="file" name="arquivo[]"> <!--arquivo1.mp3-->
   <input type="file" name="arquivo[]"> <!--arquivo2.mp3-->
   <input type="file" name="arquivo[]"> <!--arquivo3.mp3-->
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

No final `$upload_file_names` seria igual a `array("arquivo1.mp3", "arquivo2.mp3", "arquivo3.mp3");`

Answer (score 0):

O jeito correto de fazer é gerando um *array* nas formas convencionais:

```
$array = array('valor1', 'valor2', 'valorn');

$array = array('chave1' => 'valor1', 'chave2' => 'valor2', 'chave3' => 'valorn');

$array[] = 'valor1';
$array[] = 'valor2';
$array[] = 'valor3';

$array['chave1'] = 'valor1';
$array['chave2'] = 'valor2';
$array['chave3'] = 'valor3';
```

Mas você pode fazer uma **GABIARRA** assim:

```
$nome = '"nome1", "nome2", "nome3", "chave4" => "valor4"';
$array = eval('return array('.$nome.');');

var_dump($array);
```

<sub>A função eval() executa a string dada no parâmetro como código PHP. Mais detalhes na [Documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php).</sub>

Retorno:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "nome1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "nome2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "nome3"
  ["chave4"]=>
  string(6) "valor4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode gerar o array da forma que você mesmo mostrou:

```
$meuArray = array($nome1, $nome2, $nome3);
```

Outra forma para setar os valores, que também pode ser utilizada em um looping é assim:

```
$nome1 = "nome 1";
$nome2 = "nome 2";
$nome3 = "nome 3";

$meuArray = array();
$meuArray[] = $nome1;
$meuArray[] = $nome2;
$meuArray[] = $nome3;

echo $meuArray[0]; // Resultado: "nome 1"
```